# How to trap specific keyboard sequence for any running console process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, dll-injection

My goal is to trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> sequence (where <kbd>key</kbd> will be defined by my app) when any running console process has keyboard focus. Then upon such key stroke I need to insert some specific text into that console app.

The question is: once injected into a target console process how do I intercept its keyboard keystrokes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was hoping that my test dll would be injected and called from within the process that was receiving the keyboard input at the time, but unfortunately it wasn't. It was always called from within my own process that called SetWindowsHookEx() to install the hook.

That caveat is clearly stated in the documentation:

[KeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984.aspx)

> This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.

[LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx)

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.

And since neither hook gives you process information, they will not help you know which process will receive the keystroke.  The closest you can do inside these hooks is using `GetForegroundWindow()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`, but that does not guarantee that the process ID you determine will be the same process ID that actually receives the keystroke.

> Then my thinking was to install WH_CBT global hook instead and trap instances when nCode == HCBT_SETFOCUS for when any window will receive keyboard focus. Then I will somehow need to establish that that window belongs to a console app by its HWND. And then use Dll Insjection method to run my code in its process

Given an HWND, you can determine its thread ID and process ID using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`, and determine if it is a console window by calling `GetClassName()` and see if it is `"ConsoleWindowClass"`.

However, that only tells you whether the window itself is a console window.  It does not tell you which process is currently displaying a UI inside that window.  It might be:

1. `cmd.exe` itself (or whatever command processor is specified in the `%COMSPEC%` environment variable).
2. a console app that was started by `cmd.exe`, and thus interacts with the console window belonging to `cmd.exe`.
3. a console app that was started directly, and thus has a dedicated console window created by the OS for it.
4. a non-console process that created its own console window via `AllocConsole()`.
5. a non-console process that is associated with another process's console window via `AttachConsole()`.

I guess that doesn't really matter, though.  If a console window belongs to `cmd.exe`, it is going to receive keystrokes first and then delegate them to whatever child process is currently displayed in the window.  If it is a console dedicated to a another process, that process is going to receive keystrokes directly.  So, either way, you should be able to hook the process ID that actually created the console HWND, since that should be the first process that will see the keystrokes.

> The question I have though is once injected into a target console process how do I intercept its keyboard keystrokes?

You can still use a keyboard hook like before.  You can create a keyboard hook that is associated with a specific thread ID, so use the thread ID that created the console window, as that is the only thread that can directly interact with the window and receive input messages for it.  Just make sure your thread that is installing the keyboard hook has a message loop.  Whether you inject that thread remotely into the console process, or leave it inside your own process, that is up to you.  You should be able to receive the keyboard events either way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try that. I was also curious. All those keyboard hooks don't seem to allow to "mute" or "not pass on" a keyboard stroke, which I will need to do. As otherwise they result in `^K` for instance to be displayed when I hit Ctrl+Shift+K in the console window. Do you have any idea how to mute those?

Comment: @c00000fd a keyboard hook *does* allow you to discard keystrokes. The documentation says as much: "*If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.*" The problem is you will get a separate event for each key press. So you will have to keep track of the `Ctrl` and `Shift` states so you can then discard the `K` key when needed.

Comment: Oh thanks, dude. I somehow missed it. As for Ctrl + Shift. Well, it's pretty easy to solve. I can use named data section in a DLL to store states of Ctrl, Shift, Alt keys (up or down) by analyzing `flags` of `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` in `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook.

Comment: What I seem to be struggling with is [WH_CBT/HCBT_SETFOCUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx) hook. Do you have any experience with it? My assumption was that it will be called every time a window receives keyboard focus. But my tests have shown that it's called once but then if I switch between two windows (in different processes) it is not called again. The same with `WH_CBT/HCBT_ACTIVATE` hook.

Comment: Please show your actual code that is managing the `WH_CBT` hook. Your main app should be loading your DLL and installing the hook globally, not injecting it into individual processes. And you definitely should not be doing any major work in the DLL's `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` handler. When you inject your DLL into another process, create a new thread to do your work (see [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn’t it?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283)).

Comment: Oh, no, I haven't gotten to DLL injection yet. The code is pretty close to my first code snippet with `SetWindowsHookEx` except that I set it as `WH_CBT` hook and in a DLL I trap `nCode==HCBT_SETFOCUS` and log it. That's how I could tell. But you know what, at this point I think I'll be OK with just calling `GetForegroundWindow` from `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook like you suggested when I detect the right key stroke. Then I can double check if the window is correct from within the console process by calling `GetConsoleWindow` once I inject into it.

Comment: As for creating a new thread from DllMain, I was thinking about it too. Except that I will need a global named event to signal the main process from that thread when the injection is over. It just complicates things with setting the ACL on it for `everyone` so that the event can be read from within the DLL, since my main process most certainly have to run with elevated privileges to be able to inject code. Plus I guess I will need a memory mapped file to exchange data between the main process and the DLL. Is this how you'd do it?

Comment: No, it is not how I would do it. I wouldn't use injection at all. I would have the main app install a global `WH_CBT` hook to listen for input focus events, and then the event handler can (un)install a keyboard hook into specific window threads as needed. BTW, `SetWindowsHookEx()` (either `WH_CBT` or `WH_SHELL`) is not the only way to detect input focus changes. Have a look at [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) and the `EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS` event. `SetWinEventHook()` is preferred over `SetWindowsHookEx()` whenever possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114987/discussion-between-c00000fd-and-remy-lebeau).